# How can you change the Header View title font on FSCalendar and add a Subtitle?

Tags: swift, fscalendar

> I am trying to set the header title font to a much larger style font more like a big banner, and set a subtitle underneath it of the year.

```
extension FSCalendar {
func customizeCalendar() {
    appearance.caseOptions = [.headerUsesUpperCase]
    appearance.headerDateFormat = "MMM"
    headerHeight = 100
    
    let header = FSCalendarHeaderView()
    header.largeContentTitle?.append("aldjsf")
   
    
    appearance.headerTitleFont = UIFont(name: "SFProDisplay-Bold", size: 200)
    appearance.headerTitleColor = COLOR_BLACK

    appearance.headerTitleOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    appearance.headerMinimumDissolvedAlpha = 0.6
    
    appearance.todayColor = COLOR_PRIMARY
    appearance.todaySelectionColor = COLOR_BLACK
    
    appearance.titleFont = UIFont(name: "SFProDisplay-Bold", size: 11)
    appearance.titleSelectionColor = COLOR_BLACK
    
    appearance.weekdayFont = UIFont(name: "SFProText-Semibold", size: 11)
    appearance.weekdayTextColor = COLOR_GREY
    appearance.eventDefaultColor = COLOR_BLACK
    
    appearance.subtitleFont = UIFont(name: "SFProDisplay-Bold", size: 20)
   
    
    appearance.selectionColor = COLOR_BLACK
    
    
}
```

}

> Even though I am accessing the property .headerTitleFont it doesn't do anything ? I have tried all kinds of sizes. Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue with the Font sizes**

Seems the font you have mentioned is not available in the simulator/device thus it defaults to a font. I tried your approach with a font which is pre-installed and the `headerTitle` got changed as expected. List of pre-installed [fonts](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/)

```
appearance.headerTitleFont = UIFont(name: "Noteworthy Light", size: 60)
```

This is how it appears with the above font

[image]

**Adding a subtitle to the headerView**

With the available API, it seems you cannot set a subtitle in the headerView. But alternatively you can achieve it like below by customizing the `FSCalendarHeaderCell.titleLabel.attributedText`. Note that below code only change the text of `collectionView.visibleCells`, so you will also have to execute this code when you scroll the `headerView`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    for cell in calendar.calendarHeaderView.collectionView.visibleCells {
        //create an attributedString with two lines and different font sizes
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Sep\n2021\n")
        
        let attributes0: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow,
            .font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 40)!
        ]
        let attributes1: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.systemGray2
        ]
        
        attributedString.addAttributes(attributes0, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 3))
        attributedString.addAttributes(attributes1, range: NSRange(location: 4, length: 4))
        
        //replace titleLabel attributedText with the one we created
        (cell as! FSCalendarHeaderCell).titleLabel.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

This is how it appears after changing the `attributedText` of the `FSCalendarHeaderCell.titleLabel`

[image]

Comment: This is Awesome! I ended up setting headerHeight = 0 and making the whole thing from scratch. But this would have been better for the long term, I am going to update to this now. Thank you.